# responsive layout into account when printing from Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, printing, responsive, materialize

I made a nice responsive layout with materializecss. Now, when I try to print it from Chrome, the layout is the same than on mobile devices.

This means that the layout looks terrible, as my page (A4) is 21cm wide, while it is though to be around 6cm (for mobiles).

I didn't find much info on this problem. Is there a way to tell Chrome that my page is, say, 1200 pixels wide, so that the media is considered as large by the css selectors ?

Thanks !

---

EDIT:

To be more precise, my layout use the materializecss grid. So, I have items looking like:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12 m6">Item 1</div>
<div class="col s12 m6">Item 2</div>
</div>
```

This should look like this on medium and bigger screens

```
Item1  |  Item 2
```

And like this on small screens

```
Item1
Item2
```

Obviously, a page is quite wide, so it should more be considered as a medium screen rather than a small screen. But still, when printing, I see the same layout as on small screens.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found what was the problem.

MaterializeCSS breakpoints look like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) { ... }
```

So obviously they only apply on screen devices, and not on print devices. I wonder why they chose to add this. Removing all `only screen and` occurences in materialize(.min).css did the trick.

Note that I had to add this to pass the first responsive breakpoint

```
@page {
 /*size: 29.7cm 42cm; -> that would be a regular A4 page */
 size: 35cm 49.5cm;
}
```

Comment: Still, it's not ideal, as a regular A4 page (even in portrait) should be way past the first breakpoint. The bigger page trick makes everything look too small...

Answer (score 0):

You can set styles for print by using "print media query" :

```
@media print { 
    /* your style goes here */
}
```

Comment: Yes I know, but I would simply like to have my responsive grid used. See my additional edit

Comment: Materializecss seems to use "mobile first" approach. So, the default styles (without media queries) are for small screens and media queries are used for medium and large screens. That's why when you print your page the style used is the one for small screens.

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with this today and figured out a way to make it work and thought I'd pass it along. I had several elements like this:

```
<div class="col m3 s12">...</div>
```

I wanted it to print using m3 to make 4 columns, but it would only print in a single column, ie m12. I created a new css definition that set the width to 25% and only used for printing:

```
@media print {
  .print3 { width: 25% !important; }
}
```

And then added it to each element like so:

```
<div class="col m3 s12 print3">...</div>
```

Now it's responsive in a browser as it should be and will print with 4 columns like I want. Of course if you have other column sizes you want to use, just put in the appropriate percentage for width. For example, .print6 would be 50%, .print4 would be 33.3333333%, and .print8 would be 66.6666667%, etc.